# Why does "non exists" SQL query work and "not in" doesn't

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2008

I spent some time trying to figure out why this query isn't pulling the results i expected:

```
SELECT * FROM NGS WHERE ESPSSN NOT IN (SELECT SSN FROM CENSUS)
```

finally i tried writing the query another way and *this* ended up getting the expected results:

```
SELECT * FROM NGS n WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM CENSUS WHERE SSN = n.ESPSSN)
```

The first query seems more appropriate and "correct". I use "in" and "not in" all the time for similar selects and have never had a problem *that i know of*.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you write out the syntactic sugar, `x not in (1,2,3)` becomes:

```
x <> 1 AND x <> 2 AND x <> 3
```

So if the `ssn` column contains a null value, the first query is the equivalent of:

```
WHERE ESPSSN <> NULL AND ESPSSN <> ...
```

The result of the comparison with NULL is unknown, so the query would not return anything.

Comment: Good call! I just checked and there is a null value in the table. Rewriting the query to SELECT * FROM NGS WHERE ESPSSN NOT IN (SELECT ISNULL(SSN,'') FROM CENSUS) gave me the expected value. I wonder which should i use?

Comment: @Josh: I default to `not exists` because it doesn't suffer from the `null` gotcha.  But if you have performance issues, it can be worth examining the query plan for both options

Comment: @Josh, @Andomar: The ISNULL will invalidate use of any index that may have been used before

Comment: just stared at a query for half an hour trying to figure out why a similar query didn't work. 13 years on.  For others the 'Not In' is almost always your go to since it is a non-correlated subquery.

Answer (score 2):

As Andomar said, beware of NULL values when using `NOT IN`

Also note that a query using the `NOT IN` predicate will always perform nested full table scans, whereas a query using `NOT EXISTS` can use an index within the sub-query, and be much faster as a result.